# Dynamic float menu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make the menu fixed on top when window scroll down over 160 pixel, but if the body content is too short, it will become an infinite loop, because if I scroll down over 160 pixel, menu will become fixed which means scroll height will turn to under 160 pixel, so script will make the menu relative back, how to solve this.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nQ4zP/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 160) {
        $('#header').css('position', 'fixed');
    } else {
        $('#header').css('position', 'relative');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: black;
    color: yellow;
    position: relative;
    padding: 6px;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 780px;
    background: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when adding position fixed to menu, add also paddin-top for content (padding-top value equals header height + header top and bottom padding)

JS:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 160) {
        $('#content').css('padding-top', '72px');  
        $('#header').css('position', 'fixed');
    } else {
        $('#content').css('padding-top', '0');
        $('#header').css('position', 'relative');
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQ4zP/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you do not need any javascript here...so remove all js... and edit  your css:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: black;
    color: yellow;
    position: fixed; /* make menu header always fixed */
    padding: 6px;
    top:0px;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 780px;
    margin-top:72px; /* margin top 72px because of header height is 60px + pedding 6px*2  */
    background: gray;
}
```